# Complete sufficient statistic and unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, distributions, unbiased-estimator, estimators, complete-statistics

I am now studying complete sufficient statistic. My question is: Is there any relationship between the existence of complete sufficient statistic and the existence of unbiased estimator?

I know that by Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem, if an unbiased estimator of $\theta$(parameter) exists as a function of a complete sufficient statistic, then it should be unique up to a.s. sense. What I am wondering is: Can we always find such an unbiased estimator if we have complete sufficient statistic? Or conversely, if an unbiased estimator of $\theta$(parameter) exists as a function of a sufficient statistic, does that imply that the sufficient statistic is complete?

I tried to come up with some examples but failed to think of any. For example, is there an example s.t. a complete sufficient statistic exists whereas an unbiased estimator does not exists as a function of the complete sufficient statistic? I'd really appreciate your comment. Thanks!

Comment: There are situations, where an unbiased estimator does not exist even though a sufficient statistic exists. One example is for $\vartheta$ for $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n, 1/\vartheta)$.

Comment: And the Binomial admits a complete statistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we always find such an unbiased estimator if we have complete sufficient statistic?

A slight modification of the one given in the comments. Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ follow $B(m,\theta)$. Then the function $g(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}$ doesn't admit an unbiased estimator while $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$ is a Complete Sufficient Statistic.

> Or conversely, if an unbiased estimator of θ(parameter) exists as a function of a sufficient statistic, does that imply that the sufficient statistic is complete?

Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n$ follow $P(\theta)$ then $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{{(X_i-\bar{X}})}^2$ is an unbiased estimator and is a function of a statistic $T(X) = (\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i},\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}^2)$ which is sufficient. But $S^2$ is not 
 a Complete Sufficient Statistic.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are examples where there is a complete sufficient statistic but there is some function of the parameter that does not admit an unbiased estimator. One binomial example, noted in comments, is [discussed here at math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681638/for-the-binomial-distribution-why-does-no-unbiased-estimator-exist-for-1-p). There are many other examples, [this is one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79778/how-does-one-show-that-there-is-no-unbiased-estimator-of-lambda-1-for-a-po).

A paper discussing the topic is [A Class of Parameter Functions for Which the Unbiased Estimator
Does Not Έxist](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215092397).